Infimum for family of compactifications of a topological space
We saw in our topology course if a topological space admits one Hausdorff compactification (so is $T_{3\frac{1}{2}}$) then any family of compactifications admits a supremum in the natural order on compactifications.
I saw an exam question asking to prove that for a locally compact Hausdorff sapce it is also true that any family of compactifications admits an infimum. The solution given uses the fact that locally compact Hausdorff spaces admit a one-point compactification and this is a minimum for the family of all compactifications, and then goes on to prove abstractly that a set which has al suprema and a minimum element in fact has all infima as well.
I'm wondering if there is an explicit construction for the infimum of a family of compactifications. My attempt was as follows:
Say $(h_{\alpha},Y_{\alpha})_{\alpha\in \Lambda}$ is a family of compactifications for the space $X$ which is locally compact Hausdorff. Knowing it has an infima, call it $(h,Y).$ Then we have maps $f_{\alpha}:Y_{\alpha}\to Y$ for all $\alpha$ making the appropriate diagrams commute.  This gives a map $f:\bigsqcup Y_{\alpha}\to Y.$ Now this induces an equivalence relation on the disjoint union given by $x \sim y$ iff $f(x)=f(y)$ and then $f$ descend to an isomorphism between the quotient space $\left(\bigsqcup Y_{\alpha}\right)\big/{\sim}$ and $Y$.
To some extent this shows how to construct $Y$: you start with the disjoint union of the spaces and identify some points. It's clear that, as expected, $h_{\alpha}(x)$ and $h_{\beta}(x)$ will be identified for all $x\in X$ and $\alpha,\beta\in \Lambda,$ but since all $f_{\alpha}$ are surjective it's also clear that in general other identifications will be going on and it's not entirely clear to me how to describe these.
The question I suppose is: is there a nice way of describing this equivalence relation on the disjoint union in order to construct the infimum explicitly/is there some other way of constructing the infimum without knowing it exists?
